# Loop through colors

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to loop through colors and change the text of an h1 to one of the colors in the loop

```
<h1>Color Change </h1>
<button id="btn">Click Here</button>
```

```
const btn = document.querySelector('#btn')
```

```
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const h1 = document.querySelector('h1')
    const colors = ['red', 'yellow', 'brown', 'green', 'blue']
    for (let i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
        h1.style.color = colors[i]

    }
})
```

It's only returning the last color, while I want to loop through all of the colors. I'm not sure why

Comment: It does loop all the colors but it does it so fast that it doesn't show on screen. How long should it stay a certain color before changing? You will have to add such a delay somehow.

Comment: You can add a setTimeout in order to stop the colors from changing every x seconds

Comment: increment an counter then use modulo with the length of the array to pick the colour, you don't need a for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the logic you're after is to loop through the colors at each click:

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('#btn')
const h1 = document.querySelector('h1')
const colors = ['red', 'yellow', 'brown', 'green', 'blue']
let i = 0;
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  h1.style.color = colors[i]; // to change the color
  h1.innerHTML = colors[i]; // to change the text
  i = (i + 1) % colors.length;
})
```

```html
<h1>Color Change </h1>
<button id="btn">Click Here</button>
```

Comment: Don't forget the "change the text of an h1 to one of the colors in the loop" part

Answer (score 3):

Try to outline the algorithm in plain human language first:

- there is a title element, a button element, and a predefined set of colors;
- no color is chosen initially;
- whenever the button is clicked:

  - grab the next color from the set;
  - apply the next color to the title element.

Now you can convert this to the code:

```js
// there is a title element, a button element, and a predefined set of colors
const h1 = document.querySelector('h1')
const btn = document.querySelector('#btn')
const colors = ['red', 'yellow', 'brown', 'green', 'blue'];

// no color is chosen initially
let currentColorIndex = -1;

// whenever the button is clicked ...
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  // grab the next color from the set (if the current color is the last one, grab the first one then)
  const nextColorIndex = ++currentColorIndex % colors.length;

  // apply the next color to the title element
  h1.style.color = colors[nextColorIndex];
});
```

```html
<h1>Color Change </h1>
<button id="btn">Click Here</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to loop over all the colours when you click the button. You should keep a count of the current colour index, update the text colour, and then increase the count.

My usual technique for this kind of problem is to use [a closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) so we limit the number of global variables we use.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('#btn')
const h1 = document.querySelector('h1');

btn.addEventListener('click', handleClick(), false);

const colors = ['red', 'yellow', 'brown', 'green', 'blue'];

// Closures work by returning a function from
// the function that is called which maintains
// a copy of its local lexical envionment (in
// this case `count`). The function that is returned
// is the function assigned to the button click listener
// So, we initialise the count to zero
function handleClick(count = 0) {

  // Return a function that maintains a copy
  // of `count`
  return function () {

    // If the count is less than the length
    // of the colors array change the text colour
    // and then increase the count
    if (count < colors.length) {
      h1.style.color = colors[count];
      ++count;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Color Change </h1>
<button id="btn">Click Here</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a [generator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator) (or alternatively [a closure as suggested by Andy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69995422/42659)) which provides you with the next colour which will then be set within the click event:

```js
const h1 = document.querySelector("h1");
const btn = document.querySelector("#btn");

function* ColorLoop(color_palette) {
  
  let currentIndex = -1

  while (true) {
    // looping infinitely around an array based on:
    // https://benfrain.com/looping-infinitely-around-an-array-in-javascript
    let nextIndex = ++currentIndex % color_palette.length;
    yield color_palette[nextIndex];
  }

}

const colors = ColorLoop(["red", "yellow", "brown", "green", "blue"]);

btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  h1.style.color = colors.next().value;
});
```

```html
<h1>Color Change </h1>
<button id="btn">Click Here</button>
```

Note: By changing the generator's (and parameter's) name, you have even a reusable generator looping around any array.